# How to redirect stdout of one process into stdin of another one?

Tags: c, windows

I've searched and couldn't find an answer.
I have created a sub-process (prog.exe) that prints (printf) out a message.

```
CreateProcessA("prog.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOA)&si, (LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)&pi)
```

I want my main process to get what prog.exe has printed.
But, I still want the message to be printed from prog.exe

How can I do that? thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow.com handles two kinds of questions: 1) help me, my program does not compile.  and 2) my code is not working as expected, here is the actual input, actual output, expected output, and the code.  We are not here to perform your research nor to write your code.

Comment: A process can only have one standard output handle, so your parent process will need to read the output and (if necessary) print it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a pipe in your program?

Microsoft has an example to do this:
[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)